# Javascript use class instead of id

Tags: javascript

I have the code below and because it does not validate I want to delete the ids from the input boxes and make the Javascript use the class (class="filterCat") instead of the id. How do I do that?

Thanks.

```
<form id="adv_searchform" action="/" method="get" name="adv_searchform" onsubmit="return manageMultipleCategoriesSearch()">
  Search: 
  <input id="adv_s" class="input input_large" type="text" name="s" value="" />
  <h3>Category filter:</h3>
  <ul id="catSearchFilters">
<li><input type="checkbox" id="filterCat" class="filterCat" value="38">Announcements</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="filterCat" class="filterCat" value="39">Commentary</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="filterCat" class="filterCat" value="1">Uncategorized</li></ul>  <div class="clear"></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="cat" value="" />
  <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>

<script>
function manageMultipleCategoriesSearch(){

  var selectedCats = "";
  var isFirst = true;

  for (i=0; i<document.adv_searchform.filterCat.length; i++){
    if (document.adv_searchform.filterCat[i].checked == true){

    if (!isFirst)
      selectedCats += ',';

      selectedCats += document.adv_searchform.filterCat[i].value;
      isFirst = false;
    }
  }

  document.adv_searchform.cat.value = selectedCats;

  return true;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use name instead of id. and you should use different name for different checkboxes.

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="filterCat1" class="filterCat" value="38">Announcements</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="filterCat2" class="filterCat" value="39">Commentary</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="filterCat3" class="filterCat" value="1">Uncategorized</li></ul>  <div class="clear"></div>
```

JS

```
var check = document.getElementsByClassName("filterCat");
for (i=0; i<check .length; i++){
    if (check[i].checked == true){

    if (!isFirst)
      selectedCats += ',';

      selectedCats += check [i].value;
      isFirst = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not a solution to use name. I use PHP that takes the name of input and if I add name to other inputs then I must modify the PHP code a lot. Thanks.

Comment: You should't use same id for two or more element in same document.

Comment: I modiefied your js code to use class. this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('filterCat')
```

Comment: Create a new variable like so `var filterCat = document.getElementsByClassName('filterCat');` and then use it whenever you would be calling the input form of "filterCat" id

Comment: By the way, this isn't compatible with IE8. If you're lucky, though, you don't have to support it :)

Comment: I would suggest you to use jQuery cause minitech has pointed out important thing. It is easier to do validation and more likely to work in IE and other browsers if you use jQuery. Plus a good tutorial for getting id of an element in IE when using forms here http://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/

Comment: @jacek_podwysocki Thanks. I will try t use jQuery but for now it is good so.